# update-database Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am currently learning ASP.Net Core Web App (MVC), and facing an unexpected error when running update-database command in Package Manager Console after add-migration.

steps followed in PackageManager Console:

```
add-migration xyz
update-database
```

Error:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

I have installed all related Entity Framework dependencies (version 6.0.0)

This is the connection string I have made in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=server_name;Database=db_name;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

and this is what I have updated in program.cs :

```
var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<db_name>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer("connectionString"));
```

to create DB context I have written this in the respective class:

```
public class DBxyz : DbContext
    {
        public DBxyz(DbContextOptions<DBxyz> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<table_1> t1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<table_2> t2 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<table_3> t3 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<table_4> t4 { get; set; }
    }
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Is there a stacktrace shown, or is it just the one line of error message?

Comment: one line error in Package Manaager console

Comment: `"connectionString"` - remove  string quotes.

Comment: It worked! removed the " " from connectionString